# Setting Environment in systemd

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm on Debian 8 and I need to set JAVA_HOME in my service. I'm putting this is a script so it needs to query the system first as its not always going to be the same. From command line the ExecStart line works fine but not when I put it in this service. I receive:

```
Aug 12 17:03:16 debian jsvc[6761]: Invalid option -f
Aug 12 17:03:16 debian jsvc[6761]: Cannot parse command line arguments
Aug 12 17:03:16 debian systemd[1]: App1.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 12 17:03:16 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start App1.
-- Subject: Unit App1.service has failed
```

My Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=App1
After=syslog.target


[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/jsvc -user root -home ${readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::"} -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/local/app1.jar -pidfile /var/run/app1 -pidfile
Type=forking
```

Comment: Can you move that shell code to a script, then `ExecStart` that script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exec line will be split on spaces and each word passed as an arg to the command. The simplest solution for you is to enclose the entire command in single quotes and add `/bin/bash -c` in front of it:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'exec /usr/bin/jsvc -user ... -pidfile'
```

Use `-cv` initially so you can see in the logs what line was passed. I also presume you want `$()` not `${}`, which systemd will not be expanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a line like:
Enviroment="JAVA_HOME=/foo/bar/baz"
in your service file [Service] section.

Alternatively, use something like
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/myapp
and in that file set JAVA_HOME=/baz/quux

Comment: JAVA_HOME can not be determinied to be constant as this is a script for multiple servers so this is why I needed to run it as a variable.

Comment: The systemd developers' answer to that is that you should then have a drop-in `.conf` snippet for your service unit, specific to each server, that sets `Environment=JAVA_HOME=` appropriately.  The systemd developers maintain that a service unit, and its drop-in snippets, _are_ configuration files, and they are where configuration should be.